# Wordpress block won't run jQuery properly in admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flickity

In the below code, I'm trying to setup Flickity slideshow functionality using jQuery, as [outlined here](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/extras.html).

The code works fine on the front-end, but will not work in the Wordpress backend, which i want it to do for block previewing purposes.

However, in the commented code you'll notice it initiated via vanilla JS, which works fine?

Can anybody identify what might be going wrong here? Is it a quirk with the WP admin?

```
// Concat Dependencies
import jQueryBridget from 'jquery-bridget';
import Flickity from 'flickity';
import imagesloaded from 'flickity-imagesloaded';

// Set Flickity as a jQuery plugin
Flickity.setJQuery( $ );
jQueryBridget( 'flickity', Flickity, $ );

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
  // Setup functionality
  var initializeBlock = function( block ) {
        
        // Vars
        var carousel = block.find('.carousel');
        var cells = block.find('.carousel-cell');

        // THIS WORKS
        //  var carousel = new Flickity('.carousel', {
        //     cellSelector: '.carousel-cell',
        //      cellAlign: 'left',
        //      imagesLoaded: true,
        //      lazyLoad: false,
        //      freeScroll: true,
        //      contain: true,
        //      groupCells: false,
        //      prevNextButtons: false,
        //      pageDots: false
        //  });
        // }

        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
        carousel.flickity({
            cellSelector: '.carousel-cell',
            cellAlign: 'left',
            imagesLoaded: true,
            lazyLoad: false,
            freeScroll: true,
            contain: true,
            groupCells: false,
            prevNextButtons: false,
            pageDots: true
        });
  };

  // Initialize each block on page load (front-end)
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.custom-block.masthead').each(function(){
            initializeBlock( $(this) );
    });
  });

  // Initialize dynamic block preview (back-end).
  if( window.acf ) {
        window.acf.addAction( 'render_block_preview', initializeBlock );
  }

});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: Hi there - console error is 'e.flickity is not a function'